# window.location.href doesn't work in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

For some strange reason my Facebook connect does not work in my app in building, after it connect a blank screen it and it dies.

My script works in browser, BlackBerry 10 webworks app, browser on my BlackBerry Z10, Galaxy Tab, Playbook, even on the computer it works fine, but not in the app it self.
I know on BlackBerry 10 you need to disable the app in browser, i tried but did not work.

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>

function fboauthstart() {
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=' + facebookOptions.clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + facebookOptions.redirectUri + '&client_secret=' + facebookOptions.clientSecret + '&code=' + authCode;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            var response = data;
            var response = response.split('&');
            var theAccessToken = response[0].split('=');
            window.accessToken = theAccessToken[1];

      fbfirstlinkcheck();
         }
        });
}



function startOAuth() {
    var url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' + facebookOptions.clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + facebookOptions.redirectUri + '&scope=email,read_friendlists,user_online_presence,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location';
    childWindow = window.open(url, '_blank');
    window.int = self.setInterval(function() {
        var currentURL = childWindow.window.location.href;
        var callbackURL = facebookOptions.redirectUri;
        var inCallback = currentURL.indexOf(callbackURL);
        if (inCallback == 0) {
            window.clearInterval(int)
            var code = childWindow.window.location.search;
            code = code.split('code=');
            code = code[1];
            window.authCode = code;
            childWindow.close();

            setTimeout(function() {


            fboauthstart();




            }, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

I try to replace the href with assign, replace but also not worked and then on the computer it didn't work anymore.

I tried to change window.open to window.location.assign but also that did not work.
Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use this

```
window.location.replace("link.html");
```

Comment: I tried this solution, works fine in the browser but still no Cordova love. Is there a specific plugin to install from cordova? Seems so trivial...

Comment: You need to make sure the website your are navigating to is white listed in the config.xml At least that is the only way it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

InAppBrowser plugin "transforms" the javascript window.open function. It will not return a Window object any more but a InAppWindow.

You can still poll the children window, but by executing remote script:

```
var win = window.open( "http://...." );

            win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() {
                var loop = setInterval(function() {
                    win.executeScript(
                        {
                            code: "window.myData"
                        },
                        function( values ) {
                            alert(values[0]);
                        }
                    );
                });
            });
```